# How to enable ribbon buttons after ribbon load vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I would like to enable select buttons on a custom ribbon after a user registers. I am having problems getting back to the ribbon load command.

```
Sub Button_Enabled(control as IRibbonControl)

    BtnRegistration.Enabled = False
    BtnSetup.Enabled = True
    BtnBuild.Enabled = True

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify ribbons directly, but you can set a getEnabled callback and return a boolean. Here is a C# example, should be simple enough to do the same in VB.

Ribbon XML:

```
<button idMso="ClearFormatting" getEnabled="HasRegistered" />
```

Code:

```
public bool HasRegistered()
{
    return User.IsRegistered;
}
```

Once you have completed registration, invalidate the ribbon.

```
ribbon.Invalidate(); // all controls
ribbon.InvalidateControl(id); // only one control
```

Comment: Thank you. I have also found the following to work. Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.<name of ribbon control>  and it will allow access and control from any class or module